# PHP doesn't preform calucation

Tags: php

I've a php form the user enters their height and weight and once they click submit the info is resubmitted into the form and a calucation for bmi should excute and display the result. I'm a little unsure how to do this with my code and I've already checked for errors phpcodechecker.com found none, but I don't get the result. So I'm unsure if the calculation is even happening at all. Any help on how to calculate BMI off the info the user enters would be appreciated.

The forumal I need too use is

BMI = (weight in pounds * 703) / (height in inches) squared
NOTE: there are 12 inches to a foot
So, if a person weighs 150 pounds and is 6 feet tall, the calculation is
BMI = (150 * 703) / 72 x 72    (6 feet = 72 inches, then squared)

Code Below:

```
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <label for="weight">Enter your weight in pounds:</label><br>
    <input id="weight" name="weight" type="text" value="<?php echo $weight; ?>" size="30"><br>
    <label for="height">Enter your height in inches:</label><br>
    <input id="height" name="height" type="text" value="<?php echo $height; ?>" size="30"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate">
  </form>

<?php
  }
?>
<?php
$weight = '';
$height = '';

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $weight = $_POST['weight'];
    $height = $_POST['height'];
    $output_form = false;

    if (empty($weight) && empty($height)) {
      echo 'You forgot to enter your weight.<br />';
      $output_form = true;
    }

    if (empty($weight) && (!empty($height))) {
      echo 'You forgot to enter your height.<br />';
      $output_form = true;
    }
  }
  else {
    $output_form = true;
  }

  if ((!empty($weight)) && (!empty($height))) {
      $string = "(weight * 703)/height * height";
      eval($string);
      echo($res);
?>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <label for="weight">Enter your weight in pounds:</label><br>
    <input id="weight" name="weight" type="text" value="<?php echo $weight; ?>" size="30"><br>
    <label for="height">Enter your height in inches:</label><br>
    <input id="height" name="height" type="text" value="<?php echo $height; ?>" size="30"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate">
  </form>

<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: first thing why are you doing an eval ??? there's no reason to do an eval on the operation you are doing.

Comment: What is the stray closing brace `}` after the first form block?

Comment: I thought I was supposed to do an eval. I'm still learning php @Augwa

Comment: no problem. avoid eval like the plague :) It will basically allow someone to run any code they want if the user inputs aren't properly sanitized.

Comment: @showdev it looks like that part of the code didn't get copied by mistake. It's closing an earlier statement to check if the form hasn't been loaded before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tips:

- avoid using eval in your code. It is slow and insecure.
- It seems you have the same form two times (repeated code). Also, try to avoid this. I changed your code so you don't have to repeat it

A better working code may look like this:

```
<?php
$weight = '';
$height = '';
$output_form = true;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $weight = $_POST['weight'];
    $height = $_POST['height'];

    if (empty($weight) && empty($height)) { //test for both
        echo 'You forgot to enter your weight and height.<br>';
    }else if (empty($weight)) {
        echo 'You forgot to enter your weight.<br />';
    }else if (empty($height)) {
        echo 'You forgot to enter your height.<br />';
    }else{ //if none is empty, you can proceed with calc
        $output_form = false; //everything ok, hide the form
        $res = ($weight * 703)/($height * $height);
        echo $res;
    }
}

if($output_form) { ?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <label for="weight">Enter your weight in pounds:</label><br>
        <input id="weight" name="weight" type="text" value="<?php echo $weight; ?>" size="30"><br>
        <label for="height">Enter your height in inches:</label><br>
        <input id="height" name="height" type="text" value="<?php echo $height; ?>" size="30"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate">
    </form>

<?php }
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't look right:

```
  $string = "(weight * 703)/height * height";
  eval($string);
  echo($res);
```

1. There is no `$res` variable;
2. There is no need to evaluate user input. This is actually a very bad idea as it introduces a huge security risk.

You should just calculate the value you need and echo that out:

```
 echo ($weight * 703)/$height * $height;
```

Apart from that you are not using the `$output_form` variable but I guess you just did not add that yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, just do as follows :

```php
if ((!empty($weight)) && (!empty($height))) {
  $result = ($weight * 703) / $height * $height;
  echo $result;
  // ...
```